# Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering error with react-hotkeys-hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hotkeys

I am calling a saveHandler via a button and also using a hotkey, I get the following error when the hotkey is used (the error is not reproduced using the button)

> index.js:1375 Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering.

The handler is shown below:

```
  const saveRowHandler = async (disabled, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!disabled) {
      const rowNodes = addedRowNodeId.map((id) => {
        const row = gridApi.current.getRowNode(id).data;
        delete row.row_node_id;
        return row;
      });

      const url = "/hr/desgn_trans/";
      const axiosOptions = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + props.access_token,
        },
        params: {
          patch_emp_mast: true,
        },
      };

      const resArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < rowNodes.length; i++) {
        const res = await axios.post(url, rowNodes[i], axiosOptions);
        resArr.push(res);
      }

      setAddedRowNodeId([]);
      getRowData(empSelected);

    }
  };
```

The usage of the hotkey is shown below:

```
  useHotkeys(
    "f11",
    (event) => saveRowHandler(empSelected ? false : true, event),
    {},
    [addedRowNodeId, empSelected]
  );
```

Can someone explain how to get rid of the error?